# Spring Data JPA OneTo Many POST mapping Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to develop REST API for the video library.
with movie controller, I want to get, post, put and delete movie entity
( which have columns id (generated type identity and it is the primary key), title, genre, rate, and number in stock)

"Genre" is another entity, as a fact that one movie can be one only genre(in my project)

i want my api to take the following JSON Request

```
{
  "title":"John Wick",
  "rate":8.2,
  "numberInStock":19,
  "genreId":2
}
```

so genreId refers to Id genre table and points to genre name with Id 2 which is "Action"

**I am getting 415 error in postman when I try to post movie like below**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-11T03:57:31.792+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/video-library/movies/"
}
```

Someone, Please guide me where I did wrong

**Movie.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Movie {
    
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  private String title;
  private int rate;
  
  @Column(name = "numberInStock")
  private int numberInStock;
  
  
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Genre.class)
  @JoinColumn(name="genreId")
  private Genre genre;

  public Movie() {

  }

public Movie(Integer id, String title, int rate, int numberInStock, Genre genre) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.numberInStock = numberInStock;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public int getNumberInStock() {
    return numberInStock;
}

public void setNumberInStock(int numberInStock) {
    this.numberInStock = numberInStock;
}

@JsonManagedReference 
public Genre getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}


}
```

***Genre.java***

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Genre {

@Id
@Column(name="genreId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="genre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Movie> movie;

@Column(name ="genre")
private String genre;



public Genre() {

}



public Genre(Integer id, Set<Movie> movie, String genre) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.movie = movie;
    this.genre = genre;
}



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@JsonBackReference
public Set<Movie> getMovie() {
    return movie;
}


public void setMovie(Set<Movie> movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}



public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}



public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}



}
```

***MovieRestcontroller***

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/video-library")
public class MovieController {

  @Autowired
  private  MoiveRepository movieRepository;



  //CRATE
  //Add movie
  @PostMapping("/movies")
  public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie)
  {
    return movieRepository.save(movie);
  }

  //READ
  //Get a list of all movies
  @GetMapping("/movies")
  public List<Movie> getAllMovie(){
    return movieRepository.findAll();
  }

  //Get single movie
  @GetMapping("/movies/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Movie> getMovieById(@PathVariable Integer id){
    Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->
      new ResourseNotFoundException("404 Error: Movie not exist with the Given "+id));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(movie);
  }

  //UPDATE
  //Updated movie
  @PutMapping("/movies/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity <Movie> updateMovie(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Movie movieDetails){
    Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow((() ->
      new ResourseNotFoundException("404 Error: Movie not exist with the Given "+id)));


    movie.setTitle(movieDetails.getTitle());
    movie.setRate(movieDetails.getRate());
//    movie.setGenre(movieDetails.getGenre());
    movie.setNumberInStock(movieDetails.getNumberInStock());

    Movie updateMovie = movieRepository.save(movie);
    Map<String,Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("Movie Updated Successfully",Boolean.TRUE);
    return  ResponseEntity.ok(updateMovie);
  }

  //DELETE
  //Delete movie
  @DeleteMapping("/movies/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity <Map<String, Boolean>> deleteMovie(@PathVariable Integer id){
    Movie employee = movieRepository.findById(id)
      .orElseThrow((() -> new ResourseNotFoundException("404 Error: Movie not exist with the Given "+id)));
    movieRepository.delete(employee);
    Map<String,Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("Movie Deleted Successfully",Boolean.TRUE);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
  }
  
  
}
```

***GenreController***

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/video-library")
public class GenreController {
    @Autowired
    public GenreRepository genreRepository;
    
    
      @PostMapping("/genre")
      public Genre createGenre(@RequestBody Genre genre)
      {
        return genreRepository.save(genre);
      }
      
      @GetMapping("/genre")
      public List<Genre> getAllGenre(){
        return genreRepository.findAll();
      }


      @GetMapping("/genre/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<Genre> getGenreById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Genre genre = genreRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->
          new ResourseNotFoundException("404 Error: Genre not exist with the Given "+id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genre);
      }
}
```

Comment: Which client do you use to test your REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `consumes` and `produces` attributes in your `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` annotations like:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/genre",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

@GetMapping(path = "/movies/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

You are passing wrong request. Your request should contain `genre` as an object.
try

```
{
  "title":"John Wick",
  "rate":8.2,
  "numberInStock":19,
  "genre":{"genreId":2}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Nitin, I have tried adding the attributes as you suggest, but still, I'm getting the 415 response, if I manually add data in tables perform Get method from movie I'm getting this following response                                                 ``` 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "John Wick",
        "rate": 9,
        "numberInStock": 19,
        "genre": {
            "id": 1,
            "genre": "Action"
        }
    }                                                                                                                                  ```

Comment: As suggested by @tashkhisi try adding Content-type and accepts header as application/json type in post request.

Comment: I want to pass only genreId which can point to genre. genre table contains one genreId and genre. my intention is to store genres like 1 for action, 2 for comdey and etc

Comment: But in your Movie class you don't have any variable named as genreId and genre is an object of Genre. You are trying to pass an int value to an Genre Object which would fail. You can just pass id of genre as "genre":{"genreId":2} in your main request. I have updated same.

Comment: is it possible to take an int value by creating a new variable and assign it to the genre id in genre table and so that it can instead of passing another object into a request?

Comment: It would not be a good way but you can create a non-column variable (no column annotation in Entity) genreId in Movie class. Get the int value from the Movie object and then get necessary Genre object and assign to genre variable of movie and then update your entity. This is not recommended though you can do this way if you cant send direct object to genre in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Which client do you use to test your REST API?

All clients have options that let you set `Content-type:application/json` header on your request.

In Postman select `Body` tab then `raw` and then change `TEXT` in the right hand side to `JSON`.

Comment: Yes I am testing by sending JSON,  I'm sure I choose Body > Raw > JSON

Comment: I am sure there is something to do with relationship mapping, if commented out both `@OneToMany` in genre class and `@ManyToOne` in Movie class along with their constructors, setters, and getters and perform Post method for movies it is taking other three attributes which are "title", "rate", "numberInStock".